# Entiry Framework Core Complex type as primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

The official documentation has the following description

> EF Core supports using properties of any primitive type as the primary key

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#key-types-and-values

This shows that it is not possible to use the Complex type as a primary key.
Is this understanding correct?

In fact, the following code both resulted in errors.

```cs
entity.HasKey(e => new {e.SalesOrderKey.SalesOrderId, e.SalesOrderKey.SalesOrderDetailId});
entity.HasKey(e => e.SalesOrderKey);
```

This is an example of the SalesOrderDetail table in Adventure Works, a sample SQL Server database.

[image]

Comment: You may be able to use a complex type as a key if that complex type [can be and is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#key-types-and-values) manually converted to an applicable primitive type. An anonymous type wont have any conversion to a primitive type, so I don't believe you could get that to work without helper methods etc..

Comment: You could map the key columns on `SalesOrderDetail` as shadow properties. Then define a `class SalesOrderKey` as an owned type with no other columns. But that seems like pointless complexity to me.

Comment: You could also define an interface `ISalesOrderKey` that both `SalesOrderDetail` and `SalesOrderKey` implement. Then helper methods to `query.Where(d => d.SalesOrderID == arg.SalesOrderID ... )`, but that also feels like it adds complexity rather than removes it.

Comment: @DekuDesu  Does helper methods mean [convertor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-value-converter)? I don't think the converter can handle multiple columns. Is that wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily, what I mean, is I don't believe you're going to find a already pre-made method of using complex types. And any way might involve using 'helper methods' such as methods that you make and call to change data before and after you use it as a key. I don't believe it would be possible, at least not easily. It look like you might have to stick with using a primitive as a key.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The shadow properties are very close. However, Entity does not want to rely on EF Core. So I don't think we can convert shadow properties to keyless objects.

Comment: @DekuDesu I understood. Is it still difficult? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah I don't believe it's possible. However I am not an expert at EF Core. Hopefully an expert will drop by and give their opinion on the matter. Sorry!

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I didn't understand the interface and helper method method. I will look into it.If the complexity can be solved by code generation, etc., I think that's fine.
Thanks!