# (Shadow) properties of complex object as primary key in EF core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I basically want to use a complex object's properties as primary key but I can't figure out the configuration. It is a bit more complex cause I also want to add a FK to the PK.

Here [Entiry Framework Core Complex type as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67628759/entiry-framework-core-complex-type-as-primary-key) it is mentioned in the comments that it may be possible with shadow properties but I can't figure it out.

Here is a minimal example of the problem.

```
public record class Coordinate(int X, int Y);


public class Class1
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Class2> Classes2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
}

// Entity configuration Class1
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
// This creates a shadow property in Class2 with name Id
builder.HasMany(x => x.Classes2)
                            .WithOne().IsRequired()
                            .HasForeignKey("Id");


// Entity configuration Class2
// This should create two shadow properties named Coordinate_X and Coordinate_Y
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Coordinate);

// This is where it goes wrong. While the shadow property Id is found
// the other two are not.
builder.HasKey("Id", "Coordinate_X", "Coordinate_Y");
```

I keep getting this error when adding the migration:
The property 'Coordinate_X' cannot be added to the type 'Class2' because no property type was specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property, the property type must be specified.

I tried removing `"Coordinate_X", "Coordinate_Y"` from HasKey and then I can generate migrations and create a database. When I check the database both the properties are in there so I don't understand why it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you can add another complex object as primary key, for me it sounds conceptually wrong.
Below is example of what I did for one to many relationship. I hope it can help you.
Class:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Index("ProjectIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ProjectState State { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> AssignedUsers { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        Topics = new List<Topic>();
        AssignedUsers = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}

public partial class Topic
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Topic()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
}
```

Map:

```
public class ProjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            ;

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedAt)
            .IsRequired()
            ;

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(4000);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Project");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedAt).HasColumnName("CreatedAt");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
    }
}

public TopicMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(500)
        ;

    this.Property(t => t.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(1000);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Topic");
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");

    // Relationships
    this.HasRequired(t => t.Project)
        .WithMany(t => t.Topics)
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("ProjectReferenceId"));
}
```